# One web app accessing different databases with the same structure

Tags: java, web, spring-roo, multi-tenant

I created a java web application using Spring Roo as the persistence layer and MySQL as the database.
I'll have several customers using that application but it has to be one database per customer. I mean, the same database structure for everyone but having one database(schema) per customer. So how to do that using the current technologies in my application?
I was thinking of something like a URL parameter indicating what schema to use, for example:

> Customer 1 should use: http://www.myapp.com/?schema=dbcustomer1
>
> Customer 2 should use: http://www.myapp.com/?schema=dbcustomer2

So now I'm wondering how to pass that schema param value to the Spring Roo's database connection at runtime. Currently it's hard coded in the `database.properties` file generated by Roo?

Please, also let me know if you think there is a better approach to achieve that.

Thank you,

Gyo

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your Spring Roo application just the way you approach multi-tenancy in a traditional Spring based application.